# Windows Phone AutoCompleteBox display Dropdown without text input

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my application i use an AutoCompleteBox, on tap of the AutoCompleteBox i fetch the data from the server and populate the itemsource. While typing it displays the dropdown based on the text input. I would like the dropdown to be displayed without me having to input any text. Any inputs on this?

Comment: There is the MinimumPrefixLength property, did you try to set it to 0?

Comment: Yes that is set to 0, but the behavior is still the same. Does not show the drop down unless we type.